# i am importing a async function and trying to use it

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

The following is my async function to read the data

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {

    foo: async () => {
        const a = async () => {
            filedata = await fs.readFile('./scripts/pairs.json');
            console.log(filedata);
        }
        a()
    }
}
```

I am importing the data in the second file and tryed using setTimeout but i failed

> var a =  require('./scripts/2_fundAccounts')

```
app.get('/createaccount',(req,res) =>{
     console.log(setTimeout(()=>a.foo().then((i)=> console.log(i)),5000));
})
```

i am getting time out error

Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 5000,
  _idlePrev:

Next i removed the  setTimout and tryed with then i  am getting undefined

```
app.get('/createaccount', (req, res) => {
    console.log(a.foo().then((i) => console.log(i)))
})
```

Next I changed the 2_fundaccounts code

> await a()

I got

```
Server is listing on port 3000
Promise { <pending> }
(node:18637) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
undefined
```

1) Any suggestions to get promise resolved without any errors

2)plese help me i don't want to change my 2_fundacounts code i am not having wrights

3)if i have to change the 2_fundaccounts tell me what and  how to do it

Comment: I don't see any *errors* in your logs. The first logs a `Timer` instance and the second one logs a `Promise` instance, but that's to be expected.

Comment: Drop the inner `const a` function wrapper, that's totally unnecessary

Comment: @Venkatesh Muthyla Did you promisify "fs" module

Comment: hi 

i @Bergi i removed the function i got the same 
Server is listing on port 3000
Promise { <pending> }
(node:18992) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
undefined
Promise { <pending> }
(node:18992) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
undefined

Comment: You are getting the deprecation warning because you can't do `await fs.readFile(…)` - it doesn't return a promise that you can await. You need to use either `new Promise` with a callback, or [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)/[`fs.promise.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

Comment: ok i will try with new promise but i can't understand  i have declared the async function and i am using await to wait still it end and now i am importing i don't why i am getting error

Comment: Hi @Bergi

Could you explain what is going wrong why i needed to create a new promise insted of importig the function (any documentaion)

Comment: You can import the `foo` function just fine, nothing wrong with that. You needed to create a promise for `fs.readFile` which normally takes a callback and returns nothing.

Comment: ok Thanks @Bergi 

But i am working with stellar parraller i am trying to import the code into  a new file i tryed in the same manner i got  same errors 

if you want i will share the github repo can we solve that plese help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `fs` wrong. Its methods are asynchronous, but they're based on callbacks. Your code should be like:

```
foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('./scripts/pairs.json', (err, filedata) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(filedata);
                console.log(filedata);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

However, if you're using Node 10 or above, importing `require('fs').promises` lets you use its methods as typical async functions:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

module.exports = {
    foo: async () => {
        const filedata = await fs.readFile('./scripts/pairs.json');
        console.log(filedata);
        return filedata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "await" when u call "a" function like this.

```
module.exports =  {

    foo: async () => {
        const a = async() =>  {
            filedata = await fs.readFile('./scripts/pairs.json');
            console.log(filedata);
        }
        await a()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have triyed 

Server is listing on port 3000
Promise { <pending> }
(node:18637) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
undefined

Answer (score -1):

The error comes from fs.readFile, this method expects a callback as second parameter. If you want to make it synchronous, you can use readFileSync like this:

```
filedata = fs.readFileSync('./scripts/pairs.json');
```

Finally, your program is printing undefined because you are not returning anything into foo function, so 'i' has nothing.

Comment: No, OP does not want to make it synchronous. OP wants to write asynchronous code.

Comment: It only makes synchrounous that call, the rest keeps asynchronous. If he wants to make it also asynchronous, he has to write a callback method and resolve the promise into that callback.

Comment: Yes, making a promise would have been the proper solution.